# OpenGL - rotating a 2D star clockwise about its center

Tags: opengl

I am trying to rotate a "2D" star around its center as an animation, something like this:

[image]
To put it another way, rotate it like the star is a piece of paper flat on a desk with a tac in the center, and I want to spin it around. Here's some code:

```
gl11.glPushMatrix();
gl11.glTranslatef(xCoord, yCoord, 0);
// theta+=.08f; NEEDED?
// rotateX++;   NEEDED?
// rotateY++;   NEEDED?
// rotateZ++;   NEEDED?
gl11.glRotatef(?,?,?,?);
gl11.glRotatef(?,?,?,?);
gl11.glRotatef(?,?,?,?);            
gl11.glDrawElements(...);
gl11.glPopMatrix();
```

Insight appreciated. Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, so you have four values you need for a rotation in OpenGL:

1. Theta - amount in degrees to rotate
2. Coordinate about which to perform rotation
3. Normal - the normal vector to rotate around - in this case (0.0f,0.0f,1.0f) - a vector coming out of the screen at your face as you look at the star.

Theta you've got down - you will want to make a timer or put it in an event thread/callback so it can be updated to keep rotating it - otherwise you rotate it a bit and it stays that way forever

So you need to translate (using glTranslatef) to the x and y coordinates of the center of the star - this will rotate the star around its own center - as opposed to rotating it around another point (for instance, translate to the center of another object near the star, the star will rotate around that object instead).  These values do not need to change unless where the star is changes.

The normal vector is the 3d part of the rotation - because we're in three dimensions, we have to indicate where we want it to rotate...so if we had chosen (1.0f,0.0f,0.0f) instead of the one I mentioned before, the star would seem to shrink, disappear, then come back - it is rotating around an axis in the screen, but since the star is 2d, as it rotates, you start to see the flat side, like looking at a piece of paper edge towards you, you can't even see it's there if the paper is thin enough.  This value doesn't need to change as long as you don't want to change the axis around which it rotates.  That being said, it's

So, the code you have is great - just have the following for glRotatef:

```
gl11.glRotatef(theta,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);
```

Good luck!

Comment: Very good. I actually tried rotating about (1,0,0) and it did exactly what you said. Really appreciate it.